# Rest api url design exceptions

Tags: api, rest, clean-architecture

I read some articles and posts regarding to correct (clean) url desing for rest endpoints.
Anyway there are some doubts and unclear cases for me which I would like to discuss or be advised.

### Situation

Lets say we have got a service, which has got registered users. To every users admin can attach custom notes which some text.

The problem which I would like to be advised is just simply `CRUD` endpoints, which might be trivial problem.

We will have 4 related endpoints:

---

POST (create)
According to some guidelines we might to design URL like:
`/users/{userId}/notes`
And send a payload containing details. No problems here

---

GET (read)
Similar case:
`/users/{userId}/notes`
As a response we receive list of notes attached to specific user. No problems here

---

UPDATE (update)
Similar case:
`/users/{userId}/notes`
As a payload server receive `API` object with all `note` details.
Here I have my first doubts. Since I receive `note` object which contains `userId:` value- should I go strictly with that `URL` pattern? `userId` is redundant in that case. Of course I can receive that value in `PathVariable` and in payload also, but is it a correct way? The same situation appear in many other `CRUD`'s, that's why I would like to know "good practices"
API object:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 2,
    "text": "Some message"
}
```

---

DELETE (delete)
Similar case:
`/users/{userId}/notes/{noteId}`
In fact for delete I would need only `noteId` information. As I think - `/users/notes/{noteId}` would be enough, but that's mean for `DELETE` operation I would have different `URL`. It's similar situation like in `UPDATE` case.

---

### Question

Should I stick strictly to URL naming convention and use `/users/{userId}/notes`? What is a good practice for simply `CRUD` operations?

Answer (score 1):

You should review [Webber 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=188s).

In REST, we don't have "endpoints", we have "resources".  Your resource model is, in effect, a collection of documents, each with a unique identifier, than can be read (GET) and written (POST/PUT/PATCH).

Useful work in your domain model is a *side effect* that happens when somebody edits one of your resources.

Machines don't care what spelling conventions we use for our resource identifiers, so we usually choose a spelling that will make things easy for human beings; usually this means that the identifier is closely related to the name of the document.

---

> Since I receive note object which contains userId: value- should I go strictly with that URL pattern?

Yes.

The broad point (emphasized by Webber in the talk linked above) is that HTTP is an *application* protocol; general purpose components can do useful work provided that we include the right description of what is going on in the request/response metadata.

In particular, the application has caching, and [cache-invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4).  If you correctly identify which resource is being changed, caches can automatically invalidated previously cached responses.

This is one reason why we identify specific resources that are being modified by a request, rather than just POSTing all of our edits to a single generic resource.

---

> Should I stick strictly to URL naming convention and use /users/{userId}/notes?

Yes; this is, in effect, like having a single web page that holds the notes for each user, with admins editing that web page (adding and removing notes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helps to understand correct design.
I have a question to the last part of your answer. Is there a difference if I use `noteId` globaly unique in the system or it's unique in context of each user?
I mean - if I ask for a note with id = 100, I will for sure receive only one document, because it's globaly unique. Should I then still use /users/{userId}/notes/{noteId}
Is there a difference if notes are enumerated in context of user ? For example there would be many users with `noteId` = 1, than path `/users/{userId}/notes/{noteId}` seems logic for me

Comment: REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your URI, as long as they are consistent with the production rules defined in RFC 3986.   Choosing URI spellings is a balance of trade offs like "what's easiest to read in the access log / browser history?" and "should link representations use relative resolution?"

Answer (score 0):

- Since this is an opinionated question so there's no one single answer to it.
- But for the sake of good design this is what i prefer, as long as i can have unique ID for an entity like for notes in your case, it should be seen as an independent entity only.
- suppose you need to play with entity X, you only need ID of X if you choose `X/{id}` and not IDs of all the things of which X might be child of, so again simply relying of ID of X is much simpler then relying on IDs of everyone from top parent up to X.
- Imagine if you go towards `users/{id}/notes/{id}` design and then in future your notes require to add support for **comments** and **likes** and what not, In which case now urls will become `users/{id}/notes/{id}/comment/{id}` and this could go on since almost everything will be connected to a user by some logic.
- Plus, depending upon language/framework building routes that are these much connected and nested could be complex to work with, specially for other team members.